# How to get the value of the dropdown list in kendo ui grid?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I have a grid with dropdown and a checkbox. Whenever I have checked the checkbox (multi-select) I want to get the value of the drop downlist that is selected. How can I do that using kendoui.

Please help me here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MG89G/253/#run).

And my code:

```
<div id="grid"></div>

<input type="button" value="gridSelectedItem" onclick="selectElementContents( document.getElementById('grid') );"
    />

<div>
<input id="dropdownList" runat="server" /></div>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="CheckboxTemplate">
<li unselectable="off" class="k-item nowrap check-item">
    <input type="checkbox" name="#= text #" value="#= value #" class="check-input" #= selected ? "checked" : "" #/>
    <span>#= text #</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Sorry, even with the jsfiddle I am having a hard time understanding your goal.  Do you mean for the ddl to be in the grid?

Comment: so for late reply Trey Gramann you are right that is my goal.can you can please prove some solution for this http://jsfiddle.net/MG89G/253/#run

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On a side not - The template that you have defined does not need to contain li element - it is generated automatically for you.

To retrieve the model related to the item you can use the dataItem method of the ddl client object and the index of the option(that's why you need to fix your template because the index will be wrong).

Here is the magical snippet:

```
var ddl = $('#dropdownList').data().kendoDropDownList;
var model = ddl.dataItem($input.closest('.k-item').index());
alert(model.text);
```

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MG89G/331/) to see it in action.

Comment: I mean i want to filter the grid based on ddl selection for "eg:10249",(based on ddl value grid must be filter ).here my requriment is multi selection ( eg:10249,10248)

Comment: This is not supported out-of-the-box. You will need to send the value of the multibox to the server and filter the collection on the server. Check how to send additional data in the documentation through the read method of the dataSource.

Comment: Not supported means what? it will not support filter the grid (or) multi-selection

Comment: Means you will need to write extra JavaScript to work-around this.

Comment: ya i already tried some scripts but those are not working can you please provide script.

Comment: my client requriment has changed now instead of dropdownlist placed the treeview checkbox and fill the grid based on node selection (multi-selection)   here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RHh67/7/ help me for this

Comment: Can any one help me i want filter the chart  based on treeview node here is the fiiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/RHh67/22/

Answer (score 5):

This does it for me:

var selectedId = $('#MyDropDown').data("kendoDropDownList").value();

Answer (score 0):

1. The following code is for my shift kendo drop down:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Shift</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(t => t.ShiftId)
      .Name("ShiftId")
      .DataTextField("Text")
      .DataValueField("Value")
      .OptionLabel("...Select Shift...")
      .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("GetShifts", "AssessmentResult")))
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:292px", @required = "required" })
    )
  </div>
</div>
```

2. I have also button with on click event:

```
<button type="button" id="show">Show</button>
```

3. The script is like the following which alerts the selected shift value (NB: I have done some research on Telerik Kedno Forum)

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
  $('#show').click(function(event) {
    var ShiftId = $("#ShiftId").data("kendoDropDownList").value();            
    alert(ShiftId);
```

}

Comment: In your last `<script>` there is a `}` missing. Don't know if this is a copy paste issue or really missing in your code.